# What's the pattern that will match a head anywhere in an expression

Tags: pattern-matching

I'm looking for the pattern `patt[head]` that will match any expression *expr* in which `head` occurs as a head *anywhere* within *expr*.  (Ideally, the matching would stop as soon as a matching subexpression is found.)

For example,

```
Cases[{f, f[0], h[f[e[d[c[a]]]]], p[q[r[f]]], f[2][3][4], x[y[z[0,f[5][6],1,2]]]},
      patt[f]]
```

should evaluate to

```
{f[0], h[f[e[d[c[a]]]]], f[2][3][4], x[y[z[0,f[5][6],1,2]]]}
```

The answers given to a [less general question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5958128) produce the result

```
{f[0], f[2][3][4]}
```

I can't figure out how to adapt those answers to this more general problem.

Comment: How about `patt[head]:= x_ /; ! FreeQ[x, _f]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FirstCase[{f, f[0], h[f[e[d[c[a]]]]], p[q[r[f]]], f[2][3][4], x[y[z[0, f[5][6], 1, 2]]]},
   _?(! FreeQ[#, f[___]] &)]

(* f[0] *)
```